# Angular 2 HttpClient requires .subscribe

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, angular-httpclient

I pass a method that looks like this:

```
add = (): Observable<MatDialogRef<W, any>> => {
  let obs$ = this.service.getNew$().pipe(map(result => {
    this.applyNewItemProperties(result);
    return this.openDialog(result);
  }));

  obs$.subscribe();

  return obs$;
}
```

`getNew$()` is essentially a call to `return HttpClient.get<T>`.

My question is: Is this ok? I don't need the subscription, other than the fact that without it, the `get` doesn't fire. Do I need to `unsubscribe()` somewhere? Am I missing a better pattern?

Comment: The question is what you are doing with the object. you can use the observable directly in a template with the async-pipe and Angular will handle subscription for you. You could also use .toPromise() and it will behave like a promise. So this depends on your use-case.

Comment: @evayly I believe `toPromise` also remains cold unless `await`ed but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET toPromise remains cold until then is used. So yes. But it doesnt have any "unsubscribe"-mechanics. So you could avoid any bad things happening there.

Comment: The object returned from the `HttpClient.get()` is then passed to a Material Dialog to be shown / edited. I don't really need it to be "Observable", per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a subscription somewhere because without it, your observable remains **cold**. Observable's are lazy, they don't do work until someone cares about the answer (making them **hot**). So yes, its ok (and expected) although I would question why nothing up the chain is subscribing to `obs$` given that you are returning it.

Strictly speaking, you don't need to `unsubscribe` as both those methods should be completing their `Observable`. You only *need* to unsubscribe if the observable is still hot but you no longer care about the results.

Comment: No, I don't see a leak.